# Finding the index of an element is list in a Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
col_a            col_b                               col_c  
hello       [goodbye, how are you, hello]   [farewell, question, greeting]
```

I need to find the value in the list in col_c which has the same index as the value of col_a in the list col_b. So in this case: "hello" has index 2 in [goodbye, how are you, hello]. I need to get the value with index 2 from col_c - in this case "greeting".

How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
df['out'] = [next((c2 for b2, c2 in zip(b, c) if a in b2), None)
             for a, b, c in zip(df['col_a'], df['col_b'], df['col_c'])]
```

Output:

```
   col_a                          col_b                           col_c       out
0  hello  [goodbye, how are you, hello]  [farewell, question, greeting]  greeting
```

Answer (score 2):

Just added the function for `get_result_value(row)` and implemented logic as the index will contain `column b` corresponding to `column a` then will get a result from the index and `column c`.

I have attached the result as well.

```
 data_set = {'col_a': ['hello'],
               'col_b': [['goodbye', 'how are you', 'hello']],
               'col_c': [['farewell', 'question', 'greeting']]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_set)
    
    def get_result_value(row):
        index = row['col_b'].index(row['col_a'])
        return row['col_c'][index]
    
    print(df.apply(get_result_value, axis=1))
```

Result:

[image: Output]